# What does the sentence "I lit a cigarette that tasted like a plumber's handkerchief" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, literature, simile

In what way does a plumber's handkerchief taste like a cigarette?

Comment: If a normal cigarette tasted like a plumber's handkerchief it would not be notable.

Comment: Your title does not say say a plumber's handkerchief tastes like a cigarette, but that a cigarette tasted like that rag. Does that rag sound appealing?

Comment: This is a one-off metaphor; analysing it would not illuminate any general feature of the language, and is thus outside the scope of this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the tone of the sentence it must have come from some gritty story about some tough times. Mentioning a handkerchief also tells you how long ago this was written. Comparing the flavor of a cigarette to anything non-tobacco is part of the cynical mindset of a 40's or 50's novel. In those days the plumber, and several others, were the lowest of the low paid, least respected workers. What they had on their hands was not to be mentioned in polite company. To compare a flavor, willingly or habitually imbibed, to the rag the plumber wipes his hands on is meant to give you the idea that the flavour was more than a bit unpleasant, even for people used to the taste of cigarettes. It would be instructive to learn a few more descriptions included in the story you are reading.

Addendum: A good plumber never comes into contact with human waste. It is the merely the perception of filth disguised as hard work that gives the repellent air to the comparison. As for not belonging in this board; Many such questions hinge much more on subtle word meanings in one sentence or another. This time it is not so subtle.

Comment: Other phrases like this might include 'an engine-driver's glove', 'the bottom of a parrot's cage',  and 'a Sumo wrestler's jock strap'. The intention is to convey the idea that the flavour is unpleasant, not a literal comparison.

Comment: You don't even have to think about human waste to consider an old-style plumber's hanky to be unpleasant. It would have been contaminated with lead from the pipes and solder, paraffin from filling the blowlamp, the greasy flux they used with the solder, ashes from solid fuel boilers and all sorts of other inorganic substances.

Comment: I'll merely quote @jsw 29: This is a one-off metaphor; analysing it would not illuminate any general feature of the language, and is thus outside the scope of this site.